# How to schedule a task with user interaction

Tags: azure, scheduled-tasks, powershell-3.0

I want to schedule a task for stop Azure VM's. I have a script that do that, but the problem is that the **Stop-AzureVM** command in PowerShell prompts the user for a choice of 'Y' or 'N'. Can I in anyway (inside the script or in the commands of the schedule task) send the 'Y' value so the schedule task isn't hooked when running.

**Update of question with PS script including helpful answer of David Markogon**

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned 
$env:PSModulePath=$env:PSModulePath+";"+"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShellAzure\PowerShell"
Import-Module Azure
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force
Set-AzureSubscription –DefaultSubscription "Name of Subscription" 
foreach($AzureVMObject in get-AzureVM) 
{ if($AzureVMObject.Name -ne "NAME-VM-DONT-STOP" -and $AzureVMObject.Status -eq "ReadyRole") 
{ Stop-AzureVM -ServiceName $AzureVMObject.Name -Name $AzureVMObject.Name -Force}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use the `-Force` flag? If you're trying to deallocate the last vm in the deployment, this could be why you need to confirm.

```powershell
Stop-AzureVM -ServiceName myservice -Name myvmname -Force
```

You can also choose to stop the VM yet keep it provisioned, to preserve IP address:

```powershell
Stop-AzureVM -ServiceName myservice -Name myvmname -StayProvisioned
```

Note: You'll need to grab the latest PowerShell cmdlets for Azure to work with `-StayProvisioned`, as it was just added about a week ago.

Comment: Thanks! -Force did the trick, I didn't know about it as this is the first time I use PS. I couldn't use -StayProvisioned because the aim of this script is Deallocate the VM for stop price charges while not using.

Comment: Right, so... Azure now has per-minute billing, as well as stop-without-billing for virtual machines as well as reserved-instance websites and mobile services. So when you call Stop-AzureVM, and it's *not* the last VM in the deployment, it will stop incurring charges (and then you can start it back up whenever you want). If it *is* the last VM in the deployment, you'll get the desired effect you want, OR you use -StayProvisioned to keep your IP address and still incur costs.

Comment: Yes, I stop all the VM's in a subscription without keep the IP address. When I start again the VMs I'll need another script for change the DNS of my Virtual Network.